# how can i export db from mysql without exec() function

Tags: php, mysql, exec

I am trying to get the database dump from a live mysql server. I don't have db access. from googling I have found a way to get this through `exec()` like this

```
$command='mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
        exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
```

working nice on local host . But when i tried this on live server then i come to know that exec() is not enable on server . I have checked this with this method

```
if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
}else
{
  echo "exec is not enabled";
 }
```

and also tried this

```
if(exec('echo EXEC') == 'EXEC'){
    echo 'exec works';
}else
{
  echo "exec is not enabled";
}
```

I want to know is there a method so that i can export db dump without `exec()` function .Because I don't have server access.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need you own script you should go for phpMyAdmin to create dumps or use a tool like [phpMiniAdmin](http://phpminiadmin.sourceforge.net). You can also check their sources to see how simple it is creating dumps just with plain queries and without the need of `exec()`